# Python pickle running from terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, text-files, pickle

I have been working on Raspberry pi 3 with python pickle for a while and it works really well when i run code using python3 IDLE, but when I run my code from terminal `pickle.load()` function reads values even if file doesn't exist. Those values corresponds to old data that have been storage in a .txt file with same name like `lastValues.txt` or `buffer.txt`, and it doesn't matter in which folder python script is located.

```
import pickle
lastValues=[]
buffodbc=[]
try:
    with open("lastValues.txt","rb") as fp:
        lastValues = pickle.load(fp)
except:
    print ('error al cargar valores')
    pass
try:
    with open("buffer.txt","rb") as fp:
        buffodbc = pickle.load(fp)
except:
    print ('error al cargar valores')
    pass
print (lastValues)
print (buffodbc)
```

Comment: Please MAKE SURE your are in the right directory. The behavior you described seems very unlikely to be an error in your code. A more likely possibility is that you are looking at different versions of the text files and your Python script inside the terminal and IDLE. Note: Run the `pwd` command to display the current working directory.

Comment: "*it doesn't matter in which folder python script is located.*" - that does not affect the *current directory*, which is the directory used by default.  Use a **full absolute path** for the filenames to avoid these issues.

Comment: Ok you both are right, at run it with full absolute path works fine.